# Index does not exist JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, index-error

```js
integrityCheck = function () {
    var check = ['098f6bcd', '4621d373', 'cade4e83', '2627b4f6'];
    for (var i = 0; i <= check.length; i++) {
        checkIntegrityOfData(
            i,
            check[i]
        );
    }
}
```

There is probably a very obvious error in my part of the code but im new at JavaScript so i cant really see it.

Comment: `i <= check.length` off-by-one

Comment: `i <= check.length` should be `i < check.length`, arrays are 0-indexed so the last index is `array.length - 1` not `array.length`.

Answer (score 0):

Array index starts from `0`, meaning if an array has `5` elements, the length would be `5` but the max index would be `4`.

With your condition logic
You will need to fix your condition logic `i <= check.length`, last iteration of the loop will try to access `check[4]` but the last element in `check` will be in `check[3]`.

Change your loop condition code to

```
for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your loop goes *up to and including* the length of the array, however array length starts from `1` whereas array indexes start from `0`. Change it to this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
```

And it will work. (All I did was change the `i`***`<=`***`check.length` to `i`***`<`***`check.length` so it won't iterate over the last index, which is the thing making the error.